# Dynamically create Expression from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I dynamically create an expression.

I have a custom EditorFor:

```
public static class MvcExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GSCMEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, QuestionMetadata metadata)
    {
        return System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(html, metadata.Expression<TModel, TValue>());
    }
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
    @foreach (var questionMetaData in Model.MetaData)
    {
        @Html.GSCMEditorFor(questionMetaData);
    }
```

My QuestionMetaData class looks like this:

```
public class QuestionMetadata
{
    public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> Expression<TModel, TValue>()
    {
        return ///what;
    }
}
```

And I am intialising this:

```
    public IList<QuestionMetadata> GetMetaDataForApplicationSection(Type type, VmApplicationSection applicationSection)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ApplicationQuestionAttribute)) &&
                                            applicationSection.Questions.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray().Contains(prop.Name));

        var ret = props.Select(x => new QuestionMetadata { Property = x }).ToList();

        return ret;
    }
```

How can I create the expression from the PropertyInfo object?

Comment: Should the Expression returns the value of that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
public class QuestionMetadata
{
    public PropertyInfo PropInfo { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> CreateExpression<TModel, TValue>()
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(
            Expression.Property(param, PropInfo), param);
    }
}


public class TestClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

test:

```
QuestionMetadata qm = new QuestionMetadata();
qm.PropInfo = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("MyProperty");
var myFunc = qm.CreateExpression<TestClass, int>().Compile();


TestClass t = new TestClass();
t.MyProperty = 10;

MessageBox.Show(myFunc(t).ToString());
```

Comment: Too bad, I can't add extra information, because it get a `An error occured submitting the edit.`